# Is there a way to remove the "Watch on Youtube" banner on embedded Youtube videos?

Tags: youtube-api

It looks like Google is testing a new "Watch on Google" banner that displays on the bottom left part of an unwatched Youtube embed. The banner only appears on some pageloads, so maybe it's an A/B test? I would like to remove the banner so visitors are not encouraged to leave the site in the hero.

I currently use the "?modestbranding=1&rel=0" tags to keep the iframe clutter-free and on topic, but this presents a new problem.

Nothing is listed on the Youtube dev site about this new "feature" or updates to the "modestbranding" tag.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!